# Would there be any interference pattern if slit A becomes an accelerator?

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, double-slit-experiment

The same doubleslit using electron, but this time I modified the experiment a little bit by adding an electric field at one of the slit to give the electron a kick. The screen behind the detector can also measures the timing for each electron that strikes it, I am wondering would there be an interference pattern since there is a clock that indirectly hints which slits the electron took.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the electric field you will likely suck all the electrons to that slit ... so no pattern .... you are effectively making a single slit apparatus.

If the slit kick was just slightly bigger, let's say 60% of electrons went that way and 40% to the other slit then you would get a mixed pattern ....

The EM field guides it all! When the excited electron is in the electrode it is already interacting with the slit field and the entire apparatus field, it's a lot of probability (QM).  In the 60/40 case probably 80% are interfering (i.e the electron has interacted with the 2 slit EM field) and 20% probably interact with the slight kick field (only seeing one slit effectively) and not interfering.